# Get All Orders With Credit Card Payment Method

Tags: magento-1, orders, payment

How to get all the orders with the 'ccsave' as the payment method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to the database you can simply run the following query:

```
SELECT sfo.*, sfop.*
FROM sales_flat_order_payment sfop
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order sfo ON sfo.entity_id = sfop.parent_id
WHERE sfop.method = 'ccsave';
```

If you don't have access to the database to run queries you can retrieve what you want via the following code snippet:

```
<?php
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders->getSelect()->join(
    array('p' => $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')),
    'p.parent_id = main_table.entity_id',
    array()
);
$orders->addFieldToFilter('method','ccsave');

foreach ($orders as  $order) {
    echo $order->getEntityId() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will give you a list of order information of all orders that were paid via the method 'ccsave'. (You can adjust the WHERE-condition if needed...)

Comment: Can't this is not possible with ORM?

Comment: Added the Magento-way as requested ;)